# Register your phone number on the phone with two SIM-cards

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have  a  dual-sim phone and I need to catch in broadcast receiver at what number the call came (the first or the second)? How to get a phone number?

I did like that, but it works from time to time

```
public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver { 
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

String callingSIM = ""; 

Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
callingSIM =String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("simId", -1)); 

if(callingSIM == "0"){ } 

else if(callingSIM =="1"){ } 

}
}
```

Comment: **it works from time to time** means ??

Comment: It does not work correctly for all phones.